# What is the use of laravel remember me token?

Tags: php, laravel, remember-me

I have a couple of problems with understanding Laravel remember me functionality.

1. What is the connection between remember me functionality and `remember_me` column in `users` table ?
2. Is there a timeout for this functionality?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

Laravel authentication offers remember me functionality out of the box.

In order to use it you need to do 2 things:

add remember_token column in your users table - this is where the token will be stored
pass true as a second parameter of Auth::attempt() to enable remember me behaviour
If you do this, Laravel will generate a token that will be saved in users table and in a cookie. On subsequent requests, even if session cookie is not available, user will be authenticated automatically as long as remember-me cookie is there.

You can find more details and example in the docs: [Click Here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authentication#remembering-users)

Answer (score 4):

There is a good documentation on this as well [here](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication#remembering-users)

1. But yes, there is a connection and that's set when you select the remember me option when you log in.
2. It lasts indefinitely, so there is no timeout.